# How to create new JSON from JSON?

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

I have a JSON consisting of the following data:

```
{
  "comment": {
    "S": "Nice"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "1ca38300-8938-11e5-8656-9bf2d3249757"
  },
  "postId": {
    "S": "083c1f50-8b84-11e5-9021-7da869825160"
  },
  "spam": {
    "N": "0"
  },
  "tags": {
    "L": [
      {
        "S": "test1"
      },
      {
        "S": "test2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And now, I want to format the above JSON to the following format, like:

```
{  
 "comment":"Nice",
 "id":"1ca38300-8938-11e5-8656-9bf2d3249757",
 "postId":"083c1f50-8b84-11e5-9021-7da869825160",
 "tags":["test1","test2"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your json and manipulate like a plain object and then save it.

Here is how to transform your object:

```
var newObj = {
    comment: oldObj.comment.S,
    id: oldObj.id.S,
    postId: oldObj.postId.S,
    tags: oldObj.tags.L.map(function (entry) {
        return entry.S;
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes,i tried this one ,but i have n number of responses,so how to handle that

Comment: I answered about object transformation. If your qurestion is about handling a response, please desribe it more specificaly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey find the below code

suppose ur above jsonObject is completely names are and placed under result Object.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("comment",result.getJSONObject("comment").getString("s"));
obj.put("id",result.getJSONObject("id").getString("s"));
obj.put("postId",result.getJSONObject("postId").getString("s"));



List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>;
JSONArray js = result.getJSONObject("tags").getJSONArray("L");
for(I=o;i<js.length();I++){
test.add(js.get(i).getString("s"));
}

obj.put("tags",test);
```